# Security error accessing url in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder

I am very new to flex, i have created a simple login page in flex and created a webproject in Eclipse having a jsp page. i have put that jsp page in tomcat webapps. Now when i run an application of login from FlashBuilder it runs fine as i have given the ip e.g http://111.111.111.111/login.jsp and passing it as a url in HttpService and it worked fine. but when i put my login.swf file in webapps same in that folder where that jsp resides and un e.g http://localhost:8080/login.swf it displays the page but when i click on the login button it gives me with this error "Security error accessing url" i have checked it in this way few days back it worked fine but now i am stuck into this err plz help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a crossdomain.xml file just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM 
"http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

If that doesn't work, I think it's because adobe flash/flex files that access certain web related items don't work correctly when using localhost. You'll have to add it to your trusted domains at:

Updated link: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04a.html#119065

Comment: @Shaz can u plz guide me how to use crossdomain.xml file and where to put it crossdomain.xml file.

Comment: @Java_NewBie Sure. The file is saved as crossdomain.xml, and placed on the site root of all servers that the movie needs to access. So Just place the xml file I have above on the root of the server that the movie is trying to access, and name it `crossdomain.xml`. You can read more into detail at: http://goo.gl/TmNb8

Comment: @Java_NewBie The cross domain file should go in the root directory of the domain you are calling (http://111.111.111.111/crossdomain.xml ).  You do not need one of these files if the SWF is served off the same domain it is calling.

Comment: Thankyou guys i am goona try this out rite now

Comment: @Shaz I think your crossdomain.xml answer is the correct solution.  But, i'm not +1ing you because I don't understand the issues you mention related to using localhost.  Can you expand on those and/or provide a link to more information?

Comment: @Shaz OMG it worked :) Thanks Shaz and Flextras. but i want to know how it did worked when i tried it few days back without putting crossdomain.xml file. and can you plz provide me with best tutorials in learning flex and flex with java

Comment: @Java_NewBie No problem. I would help you out there but I don't know flex per say, I only use ActionScript3. I definitely can't help you out with Java either; never used it. But if you find this as the correct solution, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer. A lot of people have been doing that lately :(

Comment: @Shaz i have marked it. I don't need help in java but only in flex. but once again thanks for the great time and the solution u have given to me.

Comment: @Shaz Thanks for the link; very informative.  Although nothing in there talks about localhost.  I suspect that something served on a local web server is not the same as "local content".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the crossdomain.xml, or set up a proxy within your web app, so that basically you'd call to myserver/myapp/someotherservice?whatever, and the backend would make the calls out to the service you want, but make it look to Flash as if its still in the same domain, because it technically is.